# Should I alter my suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I made a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14574117), which originally did three things:

1. Changed title to match what the OP was actually asking
2. Removed unnecessary tag
3. Added examples of output vs expected output

Then I noticed I'd received two Accept votes and two Reject votes (for different reasons), and interpreted this as a dislike of the addition of the output examples.

So, I altered my suggested edit so it only changed the title and removed the tag, into the form you now see in the above link. It received one more Accept vote and was accepted.

Is this the edit-review system working as designed? The 5th voter was voting on a substantially different edit suggestion than the first 4, but the revised edit was better than the original edit without the superfluous examples.

Comment: `Added examples of output vs expected output` That's probably a prob.  I don't see that from the edit, tho.

Comment: @Will As he said, he edited his edit so that it was no longer suggesting that.  He's surprised that changing the edit didn't reset the votes.

Comment: Yeah - is it wrong to change a suggested edit after people have started voting on it? (Maybe that should have been the question.)

Comment: @JackDeeth It's certainly not wrong for you to change the edit.  If it wasn't okay we wouldn't let people continue to change the edits.  I could see merit in resetting the votes, although I'm not *super* worried about it either way.